# Magicsuggest setValue() changes when move to other field

Tags: php, jquery, magicsuggest

On selectionchange I am setting the new value but when it focus out the setValue change.

here is my code :

```
var ms=$('#mydiv').magicSuggest({
            useCommaKey: true,
            hideTrigger: true,
            placeholder: 'Search here',
            allowDuplicates: false,
            data: '/getData.php',
            ajaxConfig: {
              xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true,
              }
            },
            valueField: 'name',
            renderer: function(data){
                return data.full_name;
            },
            resultAsString: true
        });

$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e, cb){
            var response = cb.getValue();
            var respone_ary = response.toString().split(',');
            if(respone_ary.length > 1){
                this.removeFromSelection(cb.getSelection());
                this.setValue(respone_ary);
            }
        });
```

For Example : In response I am getting "xyz,abc" then I want to set it as two different bobble like this "xyz" "abc" .
It's get set but when I click on other filed it get change to "xyz"

Thanks in advance